# 19.04 / Wine / Photoshop?

Tags: wine, photoshop

has anyone figured out the best way to install Wine and Install Creative to install Photoshop yet ?

If not, I may have to cancel my subscription.

Krita is the best Ubuntu app to use. GIMP is good. I would like to use Photoshop.

Even if it may be an older version of Photoshop, I will be a happy camper.

Comment: Wine really isn't good for much (my humble opinion), esp with something like PS. I'd recommend installing Oracle VirtualBox, install Windows in VB, and then PS into Windows.

Comment: I know !   LOL................I am now having one hard drive for Ubuntu and another hard drive for Windows 10..........until Adobe make software for Linux.